# Type Error [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION] for my gulpFile.ts in Node/Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, gulp

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for \gulpfile.ts
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:75:11)
at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:117:38)
at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:81:20)
at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)

Hi all I am facing ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION issue.
Recently I have updated my project angular 10->16, Node 14.x.x -> 16.x.x.
I used ncu commands using these steps.
https://zerosack.org/blog/81010713779/how-to-update-angular-local-and-global-packages-with-updated-packagejson-file

Next I was able to install all the node packages but while build/run getting error for my 'gulpFile.ts'.
My gulpFile.ts is on the root folder which includes import statements.

Here are my configurations:

ts-config.json file

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
},
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "keyofStringsOnly": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "gulpfile.ts"
    //... other files
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "src"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}`


Package.json:
"ts-node": "^10.9.1",
"typescript": "^5.1.5",
angular version-> 16.1.2
node -> v16.20.1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.